# Count frequency of a column's value combinations grouped by a series of shared ID

Tags: r

My dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                 value = c('a','b','c','a','b','d','b','c','c','a'),
                 cls_code = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I want a tabled output like this, although I'm not sure if table, data frame, or matrix is the best object type:

```
   a   b   c   d
  --------------
a| 3   2   2   0
b| 2   3   2   1
```

I need to count the frequency of all the value combinations within each id of values a and b, which have a cls_code = 1. I.e., only if the values have the same ID will I count their combination

I've tried variations of grouping and counting the data, but what's really tripping me up is isolating the counts of the values based on both the cls_code = 1 AND grouped by the shared id column

Comment: How did you get your results? Could you explain

Comment: Also why is the matrix not symmetric?

Answer (score -1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'),
  cls_code = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
)
```

After using `count()` on the grouped dataset you can use
`tidyr::pivot_wider()` to get the desired format.

```r
df |>
  mutate(id = letters[id]) |>
  filter(cls_code == 1) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  count(value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = id,
              values_from = n)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   value     a     b     c     d
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         1     1    NA     1
#> 2 b         1     1     1    NA
```

Comment: This table is nowhere close to the desired output OP posted

Comment: I am aware that the cell values are not the same, but the rows and column structure is. They might have shared a subset of the data that leads to the result table. Let's see what they say.